# Unique constraint key for 3 fields

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

I need to create unique constraint key by 3 fields. The problem is that in the third field have to be unique only when field equals to 1. For example, we have fields:

```
ContentId - uniqueidentifier
MemberId - uniqueidentifier
Approved - bit
```

If we have in table record:

```
ContentId = 99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999
MemberId = 88888888-8888-8888-8888-888888888888
Approved = 1
```

And we try to add the same record so we must recieve sql error because of unique key.
But if we try to add the same record with Approved = 0 so it will add without exception

Is it possible to create constraint key with this logic? If it is show me one example please

Comment: Other way you can try it's a `Trigger` so before insert or update it checks if exists this record.

Comment: @DúverCruz thank you for this idea, it could help me if I didn't expect exception from SQL for handeling this specify case

Comment: Which DBMS?
MSSQL has [filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16)